# Systemd service fails to run at boot

Tags: systemd

I have a python script that constantly monitors a volume potentiometer and uses subprocess.check_output() to run the pactl command to adjust the audio volume.

This all works nicely when run on the command line.

I want the script to run at boot in the background, so decided to create a systemd service.

My service file is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Knob monitor
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=dave 
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/dave/dev/serial/knob_monitor.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This runs the script OK, but fails to execute the pactl command.

I have read that moving the service file into /usr/lib/systemd/user folder and removing the user reference may help.

I have done this and have used the following commands:

```
systemctl --user daemon reload
systemctl --user enable knob_monitor.service
systemctl --user start knob_monitor.service
```

This works and pactl runs as expected! Although it doesn't appear to run at boot :(
When checking the status I get the following error:

```
systemctl --user status knob_monitor.service
    
knob_monitor.service - Knob monitor
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/knob_monitor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Can anyone recommend any changes to help get this working please?

Comment: The execution environments differ. Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.